# How do I stop PySrim from running the latest saved configuration, and have it run SRIM with user specified parameters?

Tags: python

I'm trying to run the pysrim [example provided on the front page for this package](https://pypi.org/project/pysrim/), it seems to load SRIM, but it always loads the last configuration that was saved to resume later instead of running the simulation with the user specified parameters.

Is this a bug in the code? Have I overlooked a parameter in the call to the executable?